# WebScrape Field That Has Similar Tags

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code navigates into a webpage successfully, the goal would be to scrape all data under the "description" field for rows that contain this field.

The code currently prints all the tags of this description field, which also includes multiple other fields that contain the same tag/className. It also looks like some text in the *description* field is cut off?

I just want a list of all description text, for applicable rows.

(You can see a demo execution if you run the code)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#Navigate to website
driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
frame= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.NAME, "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="track-selector-popup"] [role="option"]')))

options[0].click()
page_source = driver.page_source
time.sleep(2)

description=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding']") #THIS XPATH HAS MULTIPLE FINDINGS
for i in description:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: You missed clicking the more button which cause it to populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shorter css selectors, make sure to expand the `more` sections, handle cases where there is not actually a description. Descriptions can be selected by class.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
frame= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.dx-list-item-content')))
options[0].click()
more_items = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[ng-click="expand()"]')))

for item in more_items:
    item.click()

for element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dx-data-row'):
    try:
        desc = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.desc')
        print(desc.text)
    except:
        print('no description')
```